# How strongly is airband affected by severe thunderstorms in practice?

Tags: radio-communications, lightning

In [light of this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/53790/how-do-civilian-pilots-and-atc-verify-that-other-people-on-the-radio-are-who-the) I was very surprised to learn that despite operating on a higher frequency (108 MHz upwards) than the standard [FM broadcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FM_broadcasting), [airband](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airband) uses [amplitude modulation (AM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_modulation) instead of the much more robust [frequency modulation (FM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation).

While amplitude modulation allows several senders/receivers to use the same channel and prevents jamming by the [capture effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capture_effect) of FM, amplitude modulation should allow lightning strikes to disturb reception.

In *Review of Measurements of the RF Spectrum of Radiation from Lightning* by David M. Le Vine, NASA Technical Memorandum 87788 we see this chart in Figure 5:

[image]

I know that the AM broadcast band around $10^3$ kHz is severely disturbed in thunderstorms; airband is near $10^5$ kHz, so the noise should be being damped by a factor of -25dB (~ factor 1:300).

**How is radio reception affected in practice?**

Comment: Have any of you pilots or air traffic controllers ever noticed noise from thunderstorms on the radio?

Comment: In my personal experience, lack of good static discharge has had the most effect in communication.

Comment: @rclocher3 (and OP), very much yes, lightning strikes are very noticeable as a loud burst of white noise ("static") that breaks through the radio's squelch function. I can't say as I've noticed any difference in reception range though.